# How to display images before login on login page in asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, web-config

I am using asp.net built in authentication and cannot display images on the built-in login.aspx page before logging in. I've tried adding the following block of code in Web.config as suggested in this post: [Unauthenticated users can't see images in website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116458/unauthenticated-users-cant-see-i)

```
<location path="Images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

I also tried

```
<location path="Content/Images">
```

and

```
<location path="Content">
```

but none of them worked.

Comment: I think you need to allow for anonymous users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351075/allow-anonymous-authentication-for-a-single-folder-in-web-config

Comment: I've tried allowing both anonymous and all users, but neither works.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I used a HTML tag:

```
<img src="Images/myImg.gif"/>
```

The problem disappeared with the use of Image Web server control:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/myImg.gif"/>
```